# Is there any drawback to a Vampire wielding an Undead Bane weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

For some reason I recall that Bane weapons caused problems for the wielder if the wielder was typed to the Bane.  Such as a Vampire wielding an Undead Bane mace or an Elf wielding an Elf Bane axe.  Am I misremembering something or is there actually a rule about this somewhere that I can't seem to find?

Comment: You might be confusing bane with sentience. Sentient weapons will cause trouble if the wielder doesn't align with the sentient weapon.

Comment: I doubt that.  I was more referring to actually being unable to wield it or getting a negative level or pain or something. The only thing I can think of may be what KRyan answered with or aligned weapon issues.

Comment: sentient weapons are aligned, and may refuse to activate any magical properties or attempt to posses the wielder if the wielder's alignment/purpose doesn't jive with the weapons

Comment: I think you are confusing bane with alignment-based enchantments. Vampire wielding undead bane is fine, but wielding Holy Avenger, and he will be hit with negative level until he drop it

Answer (score 6):

There is no drawback for a vampire wielding a weapon with the Undead Bane [special ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/).

Going by the Core Rulebook, the relevant distinction here is between Bane weapons, Vicious weapons, and weapons which are one of: ("Holy," "Unholy," "Axiomatic," or "Anarchic")

A weapon with the [Bane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/bane/) special ability:

> excels against certain foes. Against a designated foe, the weapon’s enhancement bonus is +2 better than its actual bonus.
> It also deals an extra 2d6 points of damage against such foes.

The rules don't state this does anything against the wielder.

Assuming your vampire is Lawful Evil, it does not want to be holding a [Holy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/holy/) Anarchic weapon.  Looking specifically at the [Holy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/holy/) special ability:

> A holy weapon is imbued with holy power. This power makes the weapon good-aligned and thus bypasses the corresponding damage reduction. It deals an extra 2d6 points of damage against all creatures of evil alignment. It bestows one permanent negative level on any evil creature attempting to wield it.

An [Anarchic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/anarchic/) weapon works against Lawful creatures the way a [Holy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/holy/) weapon works against evil creatures.

[Vicious](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/vicious/) weapons:

> deal an extra 2d6 points of damage to the opponent and 1d6 points of damage to the wielder.

A bludgeoning melee weapon with the [Disruption](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/disruption/) special ability could really mess up your vampire if the weapon were taken and used against him:

> A disruption weapon is the bane of all undead. Any undead creature struck in combat must succeed on a DC 14 Will save or be destroyed.

Aside from that risk, there's no rule I may find that says a vampire cannot wield such a weapon in combat.

---

Comment: I thought one of the editions had a negative level if you were evil and picked up a holy weapon for example?

Comment: Yep.  Just don't try to shave with it.  One nick and you blow half your face off (stupid player trick #437).

Answer (score 5):

You *might* be thinking of the D&D 3.0 rule that a ranger could not choose his own type for favored enemy unless he was evil. That rule was removed in the 3.5 revision, and certainly never applied to the Pathfinder ranger.

*Bane* weapons were likewise never included under that rule.

Comment: That might be it.  I do read a lot of 3.0 books looking for unrevised content.  Couple that with aligned weapons bestowing a negative level I might have put that together.